# throwing an instance of 'Json::LogicError'

Tags: json, jsoncpp

Creating a JSON object using [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) and have error when added in array as follows.

```
Json::Value zone1;
Json::Value coord;
zone1["zoneID"] = "shop1";
zone1["stamp"] = "xxxxx";
zone1["gridSizeX"] = "50";
zone1["gridSizeY"] = "20";
zone1["gridScale"] = "0.5";
zone1["gridOrigin"] = {"28.5", "12.6"};
```

This line `zone1["gridOrigin"] = {"28.5", "12.6"};` has the following error.

```
has terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Json::LogicError'
  what():  in Json::Value::duplicateAndPrefixStringValue(): length too big for prefixing
```

How can I modify?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated as the followings and it works.

```
Json::Value zone1;
Json::Value coord;
Json::Value gridOrigin;
zone1["zoneID"] = "shop1";
zone1["stamp"] = "xxxxx";
zone1["gridSizeX"] = "50";
zone1["gridSizeY"] = "20";
zone1["gridScale"] = "0.5";
gridOrigin.append("28.5"); gridOrigin.append("12.6");
zone1["gridOrigin"] = gridOrigin;
```